# Is it possible to register single Hibernate Interceptors multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor

Problem is I have a Hibernate Interceptor like the below:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private String tenant;

    public CustomInterceptor(String tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

   @Override    
   public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        String prepedStatement = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
        if (tenant != null) {
            prepedStatement = prepedStatement.replaceAll("TABLE_NAME_1", "TABLE_" + tenant);
        }
        return prepedStatement;
    }  }
```

I can initialise during the boot up the above Interceptor but what I want is to be able to register the same interceptor with different tenants just like what Spring Interceptors allows as shown below:

```
registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor("tenant1")).addPathPatterns("/wow/tenant1");

registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor("tenant2")).addPathPatterns("/wow/tenant2");

registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor("tenant3")).addPathPatterns("/wow/tenant3");
```

I am not able to do this registry of multiple interceptors in Hibernate and it is not possible for me to use Spring Interceptor because Spring Interceptor does not provide in my case what Hibernate Interceptor does (i.e onPrepareStatement to be able change the table name at run time).

**Can anyone please advise how to go about this registering multiple interceptors with Hibernate? I am not sure if it is possible with Hibernate.**

EDITED:

ANSWER (Based on my research and implementation):
Registering multiple interceptors at boot and then directing to different interceptors based on the incoming request pattern is something provided by Spring and not supported by Hibernate.

Comment: Do you need a number of interceptors that varies during runtime or is it fixed?

Comment: There would be only 1 interceptor but the intention is based on number of tenants (known at boot up), those many interceptors should be registered (as shown (provided by Spring Interceptor and not Hibernate) and the purpose of this registry is that when a request comes from a specific path pattern then that interceptor will be called always.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an InterceptorProxy to keep list of CustomInterceptors.

```
public class InterceptorProxy extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private List<CustomInterceptor> interceptors;

    public InterceptorProxy (List<CustomInterceptor>) {
        this.interceptors = interceptors;
    }

   @Override    
   public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        String prepedStatement = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
        for (CustomInterceptor ci:interceptors) {
             //your logic here
        }
        return prepedStatement;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I doubt if it will solve the purpose. Reason being:The purpose of registry in Spring is that it invokes that specific interceptor only when a request from that "path pattern" is received. So I can declare multiple interceptors like the way you specified but not the register feature what spring provides. I hope you understand by what I mean.

Comment: The result is the same. You register one interceptor with all the rest embedded. In the main interceptor you just delegate the calls - call `onPrepareStatement(String sql)` fro all the interceptors.

Comment: Can you tell me how would then hibernate know which interceptor to call when a request is received from a specific tenant? Because in spring I do the registry first and then whenever any incoming request comes, spring knows which interceptor has to be called and thus interceptor called  **has the tenant automatically**. Here, if I go with your approach I will have the different interceptors for sure but the program will not know which interceptor is to be called because **tenant is not known in the interceptor class** (which spring does through addPathPattern())

Comment: Hibernate will always call the InterceptorProxy then in the Proxy your code should distinguish which of the CustomInterceptor must be called. (could be all of them must replace something or you can organize Map<tenant, interceptor)

Comment: The interceptor to be called is based on the tenant in the input request. This tenant is provided by the spring automatically (thanks to registry feature) and I do not see any way that we can get this tenant in InterceptorProxy class when the request comes. Hence, I cannot determine which interceptor to be called with hibernate. I hope this helps.